# PHP explode URL with queries

Tags: php, explode

I'm a noobie to PHP and trying to take a URL like this:

`http://www.website.com/presale-event?eventId=386158&presaleId=5dbb0ec3f6f96355f00c2173`

... and end up setting `$eventId = 386158` and `$presaleId = 5dbb0ec3f6f96355f00c2173`

Here's what I've tried but I know that 'presale-event' is not the complete $uri_segments[1]. Just not sure the correct syntax to parse this. Note I only want this to fire if the $uri_segements[1] "contains" presale-event.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $uri_segments = explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
    if ($uri_segments[1] === 'presale-event') {
        list($eventId, $presaleId) = explode('=', $uri_segments[1], 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `$_GET['eventId']` and `$_GET['presaleId]`?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the query parameters and their values from a URL:

```
$url = "http://www.website.com/presale-event?eventId=386158&presaleId=5dbb0ec3f6f96355f00c2173";
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
if ($parsedUrl['path'] == '/presale-event') {
    $queryString = $parsedUrl['query'] ?? '';
    parse_str($queryString, $queryParams);
    var_dump($queryParams);
}
```

The output would be:

```
array(2) {
  ["eventId"]=>
  string(6) "386158"
  ["presaleId"]=>
  string(24) "5dbb0ec3f6f96355f00c2173"
}
```

If the query strings is related to your current incoming request, instead of parsing URL, alternatively you can use $_GET array as well.

Comment: This works. This might sound dumb but how do I explicitly set the variable $eventId and $presaleId to their values? i.e. so I can later go if(isset($eventId)) {blah}

Comment: In PHP 7: `$eventId = $queryString['eventId'] ?? null`

Comment: This worked: `$eventId   = htmlspecialchars($_GET["eventId"]);
        $presaleId = htmlspecialchars($_GET["presaleId"]);`